# Why is the derivative of a function being 0 not a proof that a function has a relative extrema?

Tags: calculus

If a f'(c)=0, then why is it considered an assumption that there is a relative extrema at x=c? Are there functions, f(x), that have a derivative being 0, f'(c)=0 at some point c but there is no relative extrema at that point c?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f(x) = x^3$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: at x=0, the derivative is 0. But isn't that a relative maximum/minimum since the point is greater/less than or equal to all surrounding points?

Comment: $x=0$ is a inflection point.

Comment: No, it is not a relative maximum or minimum - points to the left are less than it, and points to the right are greater.

Comment: Is it also false to say that all points at which the derivative is 0 are either inflection points OR relative extrema?

Comment: If your definition of inflection point is "a zero of the second derivative", then your last statement is true for twice-differentiable functions: if the derivative is zero at a point, then the second derivative at this point is either positive, negative, or zero (corresponding to a minimum, maximum, or inflection point).

Comment: @bandoo no, you are correct. If the function is continuous, at least.

Comment: @Calder My definition for the inflection point is a sign change for the second derivative. Does that affect the validity of my statement?